# How to stop Pycharm re-opening/duplicating my module files with different paths? And "Undo reload from disk"

Tags: module, pycharm, filenames, undo

My PyCharm has a habit of opening up an already-open module, but with a slightly different pathname. This means I am beavering away writing code - only to find a second version of my module has popped up on my tabs... Then I don't know which to edit, save etc. Also - likely connected - if I try to undo changes in the module, it asks if I want to "Undo Reload From Disk". This is driving me potty and is getting me in a right pickle.

I have tried researching this to no avail and would appreciate some guidance. I assume I have set my project up wrong somewhere along the line but not sure where or where to look to find out. As you can probably guess, I am quite new to all this. Also note my module filenames are all different colors too... again possibly connected?

[screenshot of issue in full swing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbE4J.png)

Answer (score 0):

Although not much interest in this post, here is the solution to part 1 in case anyone else suffers. Fingers crossed part 2 is automatically solved with it! It was to do with Pycharm getting confused with the file paths, as they were not explicitly defined. In Pycharm, closing down the project, and re-opening it by inputting the full “/net” address (e.g. /net/home/hxxx/uname/PycharmProjects/Project) seems to have done the trick.